# Describing ideal that vanishes at the variety

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

We have the following morphism

$$\phi(a_1,..a_m;b_1,...,b_n)=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 b_1 & \ldots & a_1 b_n \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots      \\
a_mb_1 & \ldots & a_m b_n
\end{pmatrix}$$

(sorry I am having hard time imputing matrices in)
Now we are trying to show $I(V)_{mn}=I(<x_{ij}x_{kl}-x_{il}x_{kj}>)$ 
Where $:1 \le i <k  \le m$ and $1 \le j <l \le n$

I am sorry I am totally confused any suggestion would be appreciate it.

Comment: What has $\phi$ to do with the question?

Comment: I guess $\phi$ is the parametrization

Comment: What's the domain and codomain of $\phi$? It looks like the Plucker embedding in coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

The morphism you describe is known as the "Segre embedding" or "Segre map". By doing a google search you will find a lot of relevant information, and even proofs of the relation you are interested in. Note that the image of a point under this map is a tuple (coordinate vector); the fact that it is organized in a matrix is not of any significance. The coordinates of that vector can be either cartesian or homogeneous; usually the latter is seen more often in the literature.